# MySql error in procedure

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `InsertInfo`(
    IN AId VARCHAR(20),
    IN Number VARCHAR(30),
    IN Address VARCHAR(30)
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @BId VARCHAR(100);
    SET @BId = AId + '_' + Number + '_' + Address;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Getting error:

Error Code : 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right 
syntax to use near '@BId VARCHAR(100);

```
SET @BId = AId + '_' + Number + '_' + Address;
END' at line 7
(0 ms taken)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove `@`.

```
 DECLARE BId VARCHAR(100);
 SET BId = AId + '_' + Number + '_' + Address;
```

Answer (score 0):

As @AVD said you need to remove `@` and 
I guess you want to CONCAT strings inside procedure?

This is correct way to do it.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `InsertInfo`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `InsertInfo`(
    IN AId VARCHAR(20),
    IN Number VARCHAR(30),
    IN Address VARCHAR(30)
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE BId VARCHAR(100);
    SET BId = CONCAT(AId,'_',Number,'_',Address);
    SELECT BId;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Calling `InsertInfo`

```
CALL InsertInfo('a','b','c');
```

returns

```
a_b_c
```